# Crashlytics could not find the manifest with fabric.properties

Tags: android, crashlytics-android

Im using classpath 'io.fabric.tools:gradle:1.+' and have a fabric.properties inside the module that I use for the fabric plugin.

When I run `gradlew crashlyticsUploadDistributionProdStaging` I get:

```
`Crashlytics could not find the manifest`
com.crashlytics.tools.android.project.ManifestData$ManifestIOException: Crashlytics could not find the manifest. Not found at .../app/build/intermediates/manifests/full/prod/staging/AndroidManifest.xml
```

Why?

Answer (score 21, accepted):

It worked after I updated the `fabric.properties` with the right data and  split the commannds:

```
gradlew assembleProdStaging 
gradlew crashlyticsUploadDistributionProdStaging
```

Without that the error still appear.

Comment: For me worked after split the commands in two lines, like you said.

Comment: I also had similar issue when uploading apk directly from jenkins. After split in two lines, it worked.

Answer (score 6):

Had the same problem.

Setting mansifest path in gradle solves the issue:

```
crashlytics {
    manifestPath = "$buildDir/PATH_TO_YOUR_MANIFEST/AndroidManifest.xml"
}
```

Comment: In my case I dont want to have the keys in my manifest since is open source.

Comment: This will likely break you uploaded APK because it has versionCode 0. See: https://twittercommunity.com/t/beta-not-able-to-read-the-version-name-and-code/60240/20

Comment: which gradle ? project or app

Comment: PATH_TO_YOUR_MANIFEST example , it can be like ?