# Crashlytics could not find the manifest

Tags: android, google-fabric

The Fabric SDK (for Android) intermittently fails builds with the following error:

```
ERROR - Crashlytics Developer Tools error.
com.crashlytics.tools.android.project.ManifestData$ManifestIOException: Crashlytics could not find the manifest. Not found at /Users/Shared/Jenkins/Home/workspace/my_project@2/true
    at com.crashlytics.tools.android.project.ManifestFileProvider.getManifestStream(ManifestFileProvider.java:32)
    at com.crashlytics.tools.android.project.DefaultManifestData.createManifest(DefaultManifestData.java:124)
...
```

There is no apparent pattern for when it will or will not fail the build, so any clues to debug this really irritating problem would be appreciated.

```
/Users/Shared/Jenkins/Home/workspace/my_project@2/true
```

... doesn't look like the path to any manifest, imo, but I've no idea why it would look there.

Edit to add: here's a more complete stacktrace for another build. `pull_request_build` is the name of the Jenkins job; it's legitimately the root directory of the project.

```
15:41:46 ERROR - Crashlytics Developer Tools error.
15:41:46 com.crashlytics.tools.android.project.ManifestData$ManifestIOException: Crashlytics could not find the manifest. Not found at /Users/Shared/Jenkins/Home/workspace/pull_request_build@2/true
15:41:46    at com.crashlytics.tools.android.project.ManifestFileProvider.getManifestStream(ManifestFileProvider.java:32)
15:41:46    at com.crashlytics.tools.android.project.DefaultManifestData.createManifest(DefaultManifestData.java:124)
15:41:46    at com.crashlytics.tools.android.project.StandardAndroidProjectFactory.createTypedProject(StandardAndroidProjectFactory.java:176)
15:41:46    at com.crashlytics.tools.android.project.StandardAndroidProjectFactory.create(StandardAndroidProjectFactory.java:118)
15:41:46    at com.crashlytics.tools.android.project.StandardAndroidProjectFactory.create(StandardAndroidProjectFactory.java:93)
15:41:46    at com.crashlytics.tools.android.DeveloperTools.processProperties(DeveloperTools.java:483)
15:41:46    at com.crashlytics.tools.android.DeveloperTools.processArgsInternal(DeveloperTools.java:348)
15:41:46    at com.crashlytics.tools.android.DeveloperTools.gradleMain(DeveloperTools.java:292)
15:41:46    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
15:41:46    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
15:41:46    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
15:41:46    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
15:41:46    at org.codehaus.groovy.reflection.CachedMethod.invoke(CachedMethod.java:93)
15:41:46    at groovy.lang.MetaMethod.doMethodInvoke(MetaMethod.java:325)
15:41:46    at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.StaticMetaMethodSite.invoke(StaticMetaMethodSite.java:46)
15:41:46    at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.StaticMetaMethodSite.call(StaticMetaMethodSite.java:91)
15:41:46    at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.AbstractCallSite.call(AbstractCallSite.java:125)
15:41:46    at com.crashlytics.tools.gradle.tasks.FabricTaskBuilder.callDevtoolsWrappingRuntimeExceptions(FabricTaskBuilder.groovy:330)
15:41:46    at com.crashlytics.tools.gradle.tasks.FabricTaskBuilder.this$2$callDevtoolsWrappingRuntimeExceptions(FabricTaskBuilder.groovy)
15:41:46    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
15:41:46    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
15:41:46    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
15:41:46    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
15:41:46    at org.codehaus.groovy.reflection.CachedMethod.invoke(CachedMethod.java:93)
15:41:46    at groovy.lang.MetaMethod.doMethodInvoke(MetaMethod.java:325)
15:41:46    at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.metaclass.ClosureMetaClass.invokeMethod(ClosureMetaClass.java:384)
15:41:46    at groovy.lang.MetaClassImpl.invokeMethod(MetaClassImpl.java:1022)
15:41:46    at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.PogoMetaClassSite.callCurrent(PogoMetaClassSite.java:69)
15:41:46    at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.AbstractCallSite.callCurrent(AbstractCallSite.java:166)
15:41:46    at com.crashlytics.tools.gradle.tasks.FabricTaskBuilder$_pluginGenerateResources_closure4.doCall(FabricTaskBuilder.groovy:129)
15:41:46    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
15:41:46    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
15:41:46    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
15:41:46    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
15:41:46    at org.codehaus.groovy.reflection.CachedMethod.invoke(CachedMethod.java:93)
15:41:46    at groovy.lang.MetaMethod.doMethodInvoke(MetaMethod.java:325)
15:41:46    at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.metaclass.ClosureMetaClass.invokeMethod(ClosureMetaClass.java:294)
15:41:46    at groovy.lang.MetaClassImpl.invokeMethod(MetaClassImpl.java:1022)
15:41:46    at groovy.lang.Closure.call(Closure.java:414)
15:41:46    at groovy.lang.Closure.call(Closure.java:430)
15:41:46    at org.gradle.api.internal.AbstractTask$ClosureTaskAction.execute(AbstractTask.java:681)
15:41:46    at org.gradle.api.internal.AbstractTask$ClosureTaskAction.execute(AbstractTask.java:656)
15:41:46    at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.TaskMutator$LeftShiftTaskAction.execute(TaskMutator.java:107)
15:41:46    at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.TaskMutator$LeftShiftTaskAction.execute(TaskMutator.java:96)
15:41:46    at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.ExecuteActionsTaskExecuter$1.run(ExecuteActionsTaskExecuter.java:122)
15:41:46    at org.gradle.internal.progress.DefaultBuildOperationExecutor$RunnableBuildOperationWorker.execute(DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.java:336)
15:41:46    at org.gradle.internal.progress.DefaultBuildOperationExecutor$RunnableBuildOperationWorker.execute(DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.java:328)
15:41:46    at org.gradle.internal.progress.DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.execute(DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.java:197)
15:41:46    at org.gradle.internal.progress.DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.run(DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.java:107)
15:41:46    at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.ExecuteActionsTaskExecuter.executeAction(ExecuteActionsTaskExecuter.java:111)
15:41:46    at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.ExecuteActionsTaskExecuter.executeActions(ExecuteActionsTaskExecuter.java:92)
15:41:46    at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.ExecuteActionsTaskExecuter.execute(ExecuteActionsTaskExecuter.java:70)
15:41:46    at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.SkipUpToDateTaskExecuter.execute(SkipUpToDateTaskExecuter.java:63)
15:41:46    at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.ResolveTaskOutputCachingStateExecuter.execute(ResolveTaskOutputCachingStateExecuter.java:54)
15:41:46    at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.ValidatingTaskExecuter.execute(ValidatingTaskExecuter.java:58)
15:41:46    at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.SkipEmptySourceFilesTaskExecuter.execute(SkipEmptySourceFilesTaskExecuter.java:88)
15:41:46    at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.ResolveTaskArtifactStateTaskExecuter.execute(ResolveTaskArtifactStateTaskExecuter.java:52)
15:41:46    at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.SkipTaskWithNoActionsExecuter.execute(SkipTaskWithNoActionsExecuter.java:52)
15:41:46    at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.SkipOnlyIfTaskExecuter.execute(SkipOnlyIfTaskExecuter.java:54)
15:41:46    at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.ExecuteAtMostOnceTaskExecuter.execute(ExecuteAtMostOnceTaskExecuter.java:43)
15:41:46    at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.CatchExceptionTaskExecuter.execute(CatchExceptionTaskExecuter.java:34)
15:41:46    at org.gradle.execution.taskgraph.DefaultTaskGraphExecuter$EventFiringTaskWorker$1.run(DefaultTaskGraphExecuter.java:248)
15:41:46    at org.gradle.internal.progress.DefaultBuildOperationExecutor$RunnableBuildOperationWorker.execute(DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.java:336)
15:41:46    at org.gradle.internal.progress.DefaultBuildOperationExecutor$RunnableBuildOperationWorker.execute(DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.java:328)
15:41:46    at org.gradle.internal.progress.DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.execute(DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.java:197)
15:41:46    at org.gradle.internal.progress.DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.run(DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.java:107)
15:41:46    at org.gradle.execution.taskgraph.DefaultTaskGraphExecuter$EventFiringTaskWorker.execute(DefaultTaskGraphExecuter.java:241)
15:41:46    at org.gradle.execution.taskgraph.DefaultTaskGraphExecuter$EventFiringTaskWorker.execute(DefaultTaskGraphExecuter.java:230)
15:41:46    at org.gradle.execution.taskgraph.DefaultTaskPlanExecutor$TaskExecutorWorker.processTask(DefaultTaskPlanExecutor.java:124)
15:41:46    at org.gradle.execution.taskgraph.DefaultTaskPlanExecutor$TaskExecutorWorker.access$200(DefaultTaskPlanExecutor.java:80)
15:41:46    at org.gradle.execution.taskgraph.DefaultTaskPlanExecutor$TaskExecutorWorker$1.execute(DefaultTaskPlanExecutor.java:105)
15:41:46    at org.gradle.execution.taskgraph.DefaultTaskPlanExecutor$TaskExecutorWorker$1.execute(DefaultTaskPlanExecutor.java:99)
15:41:46    at org.gradle.execution.taskgraph.DefaultTaskExecutionPlan.execute(DefaultTaskExecutionPlan.java:625)
15:41:46    at org.gradle.execution.taskgraph.DefaultTaskExecutionPlan.executeWithTask(DefaultTaskExecutionPlan.java:580)
15:41:46    at org.gradle.execution.taskgraph.DefaultTaskPlanExecutor$TaskExecutorWorker.run(DefaultTaskPlanExecutor.java:99)
15:41:46    at org.gradle.internal.concurrent.ExecutorPolicy$CatchAndRecordFailures.onExecute(ExecutorPolicy.java:63)
15:41:46    at org.gradle.internal.concurrent.ManagedExecutorImpl$1.run(ManagedExecutorImpl.java:46)
15:41:46    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1149)
15:41:46    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:624)
15:41:46    at org.gradle.internal.concurrent.ThreadFactoryImpl$ManagedThreadRunnable.run(ThreadFactoryImpl.java:55)
15:41:46    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)
```

Comment: I read https://stackoverflow.com/q/35371480/597849, but am not using a custom `fabric.properties` file so that doesn't help.

Comment: Mike from Fabric here. Can you share your app's build.gradle?

Comment: It is a multi-module project. The files themselves have a bunch of corporate stuff around uploads and reporting so I'm hesitant to post them here.

Comment: Thanks, in that case, I'd recommend reaching out to support(at)fabric(dot)io and reference this thread.

Comment: @Turnsole did you ever figure out what was causing this?  We're running into the exact same issue in our multi module project with distributed Jenkins servers, it causes way too many builds to fail.

Comment: Never figured it out. Still having problems.

Comment: @mbonnes @Turnsole - for me problem disappeared after I have applied `org.gradle.parallel=false` in `gradle.properties`

Answer (score 35):

We were also seeing similar build errors in a couple of modules in our multi module project.  Sometimes it manifested as `ManifestIOException: Crashlytics could not find the manifest`, other times as a usage statement followed by NullPointerException in `com.crashlytics.tools.utils.PropertiesUtils.getProperties()`.

Both of the affected modules were library modules where both the application and its library module were using Crashlytics.  We fixed the error as follows:

1. Move the following line from library build.gradle to application build.gradle:

   `apply plugin: 'io.fabric'`
2. Move any `crashlytics` blocks from library build.gradle to application build.gradle:

   `crashlytics {
       enableNdk true
   }`

We left the Crashlytics dependencies intact in both the application and library module, only the plugin was relocated.  It seems like Crashlytics does not like to be integrated in library modules for some reason and will complain about it at compile time, so it's better to integrate Crashlytics in your app module and just add the dependencies to the library if your library needs to do anything with Crashlytics.